# How to search for ancestors in a nested set model?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, search, nested-sets

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.2.2, MySQL database and the [AwesomeNestedSet](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) gem in order to handle a [nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) data structure for places (addresses, cities, countries and so on). Columns present in the related `places` database table are `name`, `parent_id`, `lft` and `rgt`.

I would like to implement a method so to find records by their names and by related ancestor names. That is, for instance, when I search for "`Spacca Napoli Street, Naples`" (*note*: the comma `,` in the string is used as a constant separator) then I would like to return addresses with name `Spacca Napoli Street` having an ancestor (in my case, a city) with name `Naples`.

Is it possible (maybe, by using some RoR scope method)? If so, how to make that?